# Passing a variable to an iframe(Same domain)

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, session-variables

How would I pass a variable to an iframe which is on the same domain.

The most logical way I can think of would be to use a session variable or cookie?

To put this in context it is the category of a wordpress page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the parent window using the `parent` keyword in javascript

Example:

```
var newValue = parent.getElementById('inputValue').value;
```

accessing the child window is also possible

```
var iframeElement = document.getElementById("MyFrame");

var ifram = (iframeElement.contentWindow) ? iframeElement.contentWindow : (iframeElement.contentDocument.document) ? iframeElement.contentDocument.document : iframeElement.contentDocument;
```

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on what type of variable you are trying to pass... Javascript, PHP, or does it matter to you?